# i want connect my sp-api amazon seller and django

Tags: django-rest-framework, amazon-selling-partner-api

hey i try to fix this code for amazon seller sp-api and it's not work at all cannot connect

```
def amazon_list(request):
    #api_request = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    #api = json.loads(api_request.content)
    #return render(request, 'shop/api.html', {'api': api})

    header = {
            'refresh_token':'Atzr|IwEBIO5ZRMBu6h3**********',
            'lwa_client_id':'amzn1.sp.solution.cb762*********3',
            'lwa_client_secret':'c99d6d067388d00c7be64150************',
            'aws_access_key':'kiDJ9rM+zBdbWmSLF**********',
            'aws_secret_key':'AKIAR4KA65F7DWCNKMZL',
            'role_arn':'arn:aws:iam::**********:user/SellingPartnerAPI',
    }

    res = Orders(credentials=header, marketplace='A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2')
    resultat = convert_response_to_amazon_order_list(
                    res.get_orders(CreatedAfter='2022-03-16', CreatedBefore=date.today().isoformat()).payload
                )
    return render(request, 'shop/api.html', {'api': resultat})
```

Answer (score 0):

my code work fine after configuration of aws and following steps in amazon documentation, it's fixing user and role and policy ...and all work fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).